# input type in javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox, input, box

```
var input0=prompt("Please enter your name:");
while (!isNaN(input0))
{
alert("Please enter a valid name")
var input0=prompt("Please enter your name:");


enter code here
}

var o=(input0); 

var salesperson;
salesperson= input0;
document.getElementById("salesperson").value="o"
document.write ("Hello" + "<input id=>" +  +input0 "<input disabled=disabled>" )
```

So this is my codes used in javascript, as I want the input box to appear only when being prompted. however, I am unable to get the result salesperson inside the input box, any help?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Also, there seems to be syntax errors in your code. Can you try out yourself in jsfiddle?

Comment: Result of the `prompt` is always a String, so it can't be `NaN`.

Comment: Just the result to be shown in an inputbox, but by using javascript of course

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to fix your last `document.write` call:

```
var input0=prompt("Please enter your name:");
while (!isNaN(input0))
{
alert("Please enter a valid name")
var input0=prompt("Please enter your name:");
}

var o=(input0); 

var salesperson;
salesperson= input0;
//document.getElementById("salesperson").value="o"
document.write ("Hello" + "<input value='" + input0 + "' disabled=disabled>" )
```

However, maybe you could consider setting the value of an already existing input, instead of using `document.write`. E.g.: using

```
document.getElementById("name").value=input0;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x6nkyjdc/